# Difference context:property-placeholder VS @Configuration @PropertySource classpathproperties

Tags: spring

I need to know difference between below two ways of loading a property file.

**Approach-1**

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:constants.properties"/>
```

**Approach-2**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.snippets.enterprise"/>

package com.snippets.enterprise;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/constants.properties")
public class SpringConfig  {}
```

I see in **approach two** keys and values are available when application context is loading. 
but in

**approach one** keys of the properties are not available when application context is loading and it says

key is not found. Please let me know the difference of these two approaches.

1. When property files are loading with the application context.
2. When key,values of property files get initialized in the container.

Comment: add exception stack trace what you getting to your question, and which file you have **Approach-1** configured? name what are spring configuration files you have in your project?

Answer (score 5):

Both are actually quite independent. Let me try and clarify based on my understanding:

Approach 1 of using `context:property-placeholder` registers a component which can resolve placeholders of form `${propertyname}` in bean definitions.

whereas the `@PropertySource` annotation contributes properties to the active [Spring environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html).

Now, coming back to Approach 1, `context:property-placeholder` actually is intelligent enough to know that it needs to look not just at the properties registered through its `location` attribute but also to look at the properties available in the current active environment(to which properties have been added in through the `@PropertySource` annotations like in your approach2).

So, if you want your placeholders to continue to be resolved you will need to use your approach1 with approach2.

If on the other hand you want to use approach 2 exclusively then, the best way is to inject in an environment where you need the property and explicitly look for the property, this way:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired 
    private Environment environment;

    public void mymethod() {
        ..
        environment.getProperty("mykey");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am unable to inject a property key with Approach-1. Where Approach-2 makes it.                             <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:constants.properties"/>                                                                                                                 <bean id="helloWorldBean"
  class="com.snippets.enterprise.services.HelloWorld">
   <property name="key" value="${keypath}" />
 </bean>                                                           keypath is a property of property file and want to inject it when context is loading.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'helloWorldBean' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'keypath'
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:252)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)

Comment: But this works fine with approach-2 <context:component-scan base-package="com.snippets.enterprise"/> <bean id="helloWorldBean" class="com.snippets.enterprise.services.HelloWorld"> <property name="key" value="${keypath}" /> </bean>

Comment: @Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/constants.properties")
public class SpringConfig  {}

Comment: I am surprised that approach 1 is failing for you!, it shouldn't have especially if Approach 2 has worked. Possibly the location to the properties is a little off. Any reason for the slightly different path, try with the one that works for you in approach 2 - `classpath:/constants.properties`

Comment: @BijuKunjummen Please also mention that `Environment#resolvePlaceholders(String)` cannot resolve properties from `<context:property-placeholder />`.